# I am getting "TypeError: decorator_factory() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

Why am I getting the above exception from running run the call here. I feel like I am missing something very very obvious..

```
def decorator_factory(arg1, arg2):
    def simple_decorator(f):
        def wrapper():
              print arg1
              f()
              print arg2
    return wrapper
return decorator_factory

@decorator_factory("what the heck", "what the heck2")
def hello():
print "Hello World"

hello()
```

Comment: Please double-check your indendation. Aside from that, there is nothing obviously wrong with what you've written; please give a [mcve] with the full traceback.

Comment: It has to be `return simple_decorator` instead of `return decorator_factory`

Comment: Sorry guys let me copy it again here.. it looks like pasting the code here gave me the issues u guys are mentioning here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be `return simple_decorator` instead of `return decorator_factory`

```
def decorator_factory(arg1, arg2):
    def simple_decorator(f):
        def wrapper():
              print arg1
              f()
              print arg2
        return wrapper
    return simple_decorator # <--- HERE 

@decorator_factory("what the heck", "what the heck2")
def hello():
    print "Hello World"

hello()
```